# How restart a thread, no pause nor sleep

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events

I've searched around and I want to abort a thread and restart it, something who should be really simple but no one is answering.

Basicly I have an user who conenct throught a form, when the user is authenthified it raise an event to connect the user bringing a new form on another thread, so if the user disconnect I end the thread and bring him to the connection form but if he try to connect again how do I start the thread again

***Starting connected form***

```
Private Sub sAuthentified(ByVal Sender As Coms, ByVal sTemp As String) Handles mComs.sAuthentified
    If (Equals(Sender.AES_Decrypt(sTemp), "$%?SuccesS&*(")) Then
        Dim d1 As New HideForm(AddressOf Hide)
        Me.Invoke(d1)

        t1.Start()
    Else
        ToolTip1.Show(String.Empty, UsernameField, 103, 10, 1)
        ToolTip1.Show("Matricule et/ou password ne sont pas valide.", UsernameField, 103, 10, 1000)
    End If
End Sub
```

***Ending the connected form***

```
Private Sub Me_Disconnect(ByVal Sender As Coms) Handles mComs.Disconnect
    mComs = Nothing

    t1.Abort()

    connectedForm.Dispose()

    Dim d As New ShowForm(AddressOf Show)
    Me.Invoke(d)
End Sub
```

***Started by t1***

```
Private Sub newForm()
    connectedForm = New Connected(mComs, sUser_sPass)

    connectedForm.ShowDialog()
    connectedForm.Dispose()

    mComs.sendMessage(Coms.enumTags.Disconnect)
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is going on in your thread?  Instead of Abort()ing it, you could "pause" it using various thread synchronization techniques.  One possibility might be to use a ManualResetEvent().  Then you can make the thread literally stop at your desired position and only continue again when the MRE is set.  *I know you said in your title that you didn't want to pause the thread...but as Jon has already answered, you can't restart it, so you might as well open up to other possibilities.

Comment: I've added what the thread started

Comment: Also what would be my other possibilities since in the new form I have a "New" call so if it's not started from the begining the form won't be initialized properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've searched around and I want to abort a thread and restart it, something who should be really simple but no one is answering.

You can't - it's as simple as that. Once a thread has been successfully aborted (i.e. it really has completed, and is in a state of `Aborted`, not just `AbortRequested`) you can't restart it.

It sounds like you should just be creating a new thread - if indeed it's appropriate to use multiple threads at all in this case. (It's not clear why you'd want to have multiple UI threads. Normally there's a single UI thread, but possibly multiple non-UI threads. There are exceptions to this rule, but you should have a really good reason...)

I'd *also* avoid aborting threads - the only thread you can really safely abort (and then continue with the app) is the current thread, and even that's normally just a shortcut to avoid better design. Otherwise you don't know what the thread you're aborting is really doing.

Comment: Well how can I do what I want to do ???, byt thank for the clear and neat answer since everywhere I look I see part of answer

Comment: @Mokmeuh: See my edit. Just create a new thread instead of trying to restart the existing one. Or just have a single UI thread in the first place, which would probably be cleaner...

Comment: Well my thread are defined at top as general variable, because I want to end it in another event ...

Comment: Also because the Form is started in another thread (the event) the form stop the coms "thread" until the form is closed

Comment: @Mokmeuh: But why not start all forms in the same thread? Just have one UI thread.

Comment: I would like so but when I start it from a deleguate I don't know why the coms class who handle all connection with the server stall I don,t know why so with a new thread it doesn't stall

Answer (score 0):

As jon said, there's no way to restart a thread, but for anyone who need a way to workAround with this, that is what I,ve used

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf newForm))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like so but when I start it from a deleguate I don't know why
>   the coms class who handle all connection with the server stall I don,t
>   know why so with a new thread it doesn't stall

It all looks pretty messy to me...don't have a clean fix for you.  As Jon said, the whole thing probably needs a re-design.

This isn't the way things are usually done, but it may help in your situation.

The first button starts the form in another thread, while the second one closes that form causing the thread to shut down.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private T1 As System.Threading.Thread = Nothing
    Private connectedForm As Connected = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If IsNothing(T1) Then
            T1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf newForm)
            T1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub newForm()
        connectedForm = New Connected() ' New Connected(mComs, sUser_sPass)
        Application.Run(connectedForm)
        connectedForm = Nothing
        T1 = Nothing
        ' mComs.sendMessage(Coms.enumTags.Disconnect)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Not IsNothing(connectedForm) AndAlso Not connectedForm.IsDisposed Then
            connectedForm.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                          connectedForm.Close()
                                      End Sub)

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

There are other issues with communication between forms started this way...be careful!

Comment: I doN,t need them to communicate between them, but thank, also check my answer it's working prety nicely